# What does “Can not place blocks outside of world” mean?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing Minecraft and was trying to make an infinitely generating backrooms, however when I ran these commands

```
/clone ~60 ~7 ~60 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~60
```

with a second command block which is underneath the first

```
/clone ~60 ~8 ~60 ~ ~ ~ ~60 ~ ~
```

it said can not place blocks outside of world.

Comment: Sounds like world border or above/below height limit.

Comment: Yeah there can be some problems like that with "infinite" generation with command blocks. Can you provide more context as to how these commands run? Are these command blocks repeat forever or repeat once? Did it work for a little bit and then error?

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequent problem with clone commands and can be caused by a variety of things:

1. When cloning a block, the location that you are cloning from and location you are cloning to need to be within your simulation distance and it needs to be loaded. If they are not, then you will get that error message. This can be fixed by increasing the simulation distance or moving towards the location you are cloning.
2. It is also possible that the location you are cloning to or from is not within the world boarders. For example, it may be above or below the world block limit. To fix this you need to change the inputted coordinates.

If these suggestions don't help, then if you could provide us with more information, that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in Bedrock Edition where commands can't place blocks in an area that isn't loaded. Try increasing your render distance or asking a friend to load the area for you.
You can also try the [tickingarea](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tickingarea) command (but I can't confirm if that would work).